# Autofill QComboBox with data from database

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I have created a `QComboBox` delegate which I use for a single column of a `QTableView` (each cell of that column is an individual `combobox`), the data which I want to display in my `combobox` returns from the database as a string of id's separated by a `;`
My question is, how do I populate my `combobox` with this data retrieved by the database.

To clarify: the column in question retrieves specific Id's (4 digit strings), sometimes an object may have multiple Id's (separated by `;`), I want to create a `combobox` for the cells with multiple Id's so the user can select which one they want to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
  QString data = "Id01;Id02;Id03;Id04;Id05";
  QStringList list = data.split(";");

  QComboBox *comboBox = new QComboBox;
  comboBox->insertItems(0, list);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I wanted. A simple answer like I thought.